# c# - check for null in a collection initializer

Tags: c#, json.net

I am parsing a `Json` document using Json.NET and creating an `ArrayList` using a `Collection Initializer` as follows

```
var array = new ArrayList
            {
                  inputJson["abc"].ToString(),
                  inputJson["def"].Value<float>(),
                  inputJson["ghi"].Value<float>()
            };
```

Now I would like to add a null check so it doesn't throw an exception if one of the properties is missing in the Json document.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would do the trick

```
var array = new ArrayList
{
      inputJson["abc"] != null ? inputJson["abc"].ToString() : "",
      inputJson["def"] != null ? inputJson["def"].Value<float>() : 0.0F,
      inputJson["ghi"] != null ? inputJson["ghi"].Value<float>() : 0.0F
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create extension methods to handle this. Note, I'm not positive on the types here, so bear with me:

```
public static string AsString(this JObjectValue jsonValue, string defaultValue = "")
{
    if (jsonValue != null)
        return jsonValue.ToString();
    else
        return defaultValue;
}

public static T As<T>(this JObjectValue jsonValue, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    if (jsonValue != null)
        return jsonValue.Value<T>();
    else
        return defaultValue;
}
```

With usage:

```
var array = new ArrayList
{
    inputJson["abc"].AsString(),
    inputJson["def"].As<float>(),
    inputJson["ghi"].As<float>(),
    inputJson["jkl"].As(2.0f) //or with custom default values and type inference
};
```

This also has the benefit of avoiding hitting the indexer twice (once to check for `null`, and a second time to convert the value), and avoids repeating yourself as to how you parse/read the json input.

Comment: Thanks for this! This will also be beneficial in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
var array = new ArrayList
{
      inputJson["abc"] ?? inputJson["abc"].ToString(),
      ...
};
```